# Jruby emacs integration

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, jruby

Is it possible to integrate the Java autocompletion for the classes I import via `java_import`? Methods defined in Ruby would be nice too, but this would be more of a candy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be off here, but:

Doesn't RSense achieve what you need? It is supposed to detect new definitions after a "require" method

https://github.com/rsense/rsense